# Making a form re-enabled after it has been disabled, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, submit

I currently have my code set to disable the submit button when the field is submitted. Is there a way I can make it re-enable the submit button later?

> **The first half of my code.**

```
$("#segment").submit(function () {
$(':submit').attr('disabled', 'disbled');
```

> **The second half of my code.**

```
if (data == 'success') {
            $("#segment").slideUp(function () {
                $("#segment").after('<div class="approvedMessage">YES</div>');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#segment").slideDown();
                    $('.approvedMessage').fadeOut();
                },
                2000);
            });
        }
```

Whereas after 2 seconds it slides back down, I also want it to re-enable the form in the second half of the code, right before it slides back down to show the form again.

***The form is submitted regardless if the data is false or true, etc. It does a slideUp, I just want the submit button to re-enable itself again before the message text slides down to show the form again.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply remove the attribute:

```
$(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
```

In your case:

```
if (data == 'success') {
        $("#segment").slideUp(function () {
            $("#segment").after('<div class="approvedMessage">YES</div>');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#segment").slideDown();
                $('.approvedMessage').fadeOut();
            },
            2000);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(':submit').attr('disabled', false);` ?

Comment: $(':submit').attr('disabled', ''); will work though.. 

Philippe Leybaert answer including removeAttr() is even better though.